# Seaborn relplot(): can't change subtitles y position

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

So i'm making a relplot and want the titles (a, b, c, d, e, f) to be below each subplot, but can't make it happen. In fact, I can't move title along y axis at all. The code sample looks like this:

```
g = sns.relplot(x="X", y="Y",
                hue="Label", palette=palette,
                col='Dataset', col_wrap=3,
                legend='full', height=4, aspect=1,
                kind="scatter", data=data, facet_kws={'sharex': False, 'sharey': False},
                s=15
                )
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    ax.set_ylabel('')
    ax.set_xlabel('')
    ax.set_xticklabels([])
    ax.set_yticklabels([])
for ax, title in zip(g.axes.flat, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']):
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.title.set_position([0.3, -0.01])
sns.despine(top=False, right=False, left=False, bottom=False, offset=None, trim=False)
plt.show()
```

And it produces an image like this:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXh7g.png)
Changing -0.01 (y argument) in *ax.title.set_position([0.3, -0.01])* doesn't do anything, however changing 0.3 (x argument) does move the title along x axis...

Tried as well to pass x and y kwargs to *ax.set_title()*: same story, x works, y doesn't do anything.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Newest [matplotlib 3.3.1 `set_title` api](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_title.html) has a `y` argument to customize the vertical axes location for the title. From the source code, I think this `y` is exactly the [Text](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text) `y`.

Comment: If I don't set the `y` argument in `set_title()`, the `y` in `set_position()` won't work like you describe even if `print(ax.title)` tells it is evaluated. Interestingly, if I set `y` in `set_title()`, the `y` set in `set_position()` will take effect. I couldn't find anything useful from the source code, you may report a bug to matplotlib.

Comment: You could use `ax.set_title(title, x=0.3, y=0.92)` to adjust the title position, though I still don't figure out why `ax.set_title(title, position=[0.3, 0.92])` doesn't work. This time the y is not even changed.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh
Sorry, I don't quite understand: did you manage to change y position of the text or not? 
Because I cannot change it at all, any number I try for y argument, the result is the same.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh As for newest matplotlib package, i'm afraid it has some problems with seaborn compatibility, because when I installed it, I couldn't make this code plot anything at all, raised an error. I use Anaconda, so my version of matplotlib is not the newest.

Comment: You can find my test code [here](https://pastebin.com/VFmyexmr), it's on matplotlib 3.3.0. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zovj.png) is how it looks like on my machine. If you couldn't use `y` argument to adjust y position. How about the `pad` argument?

Comment: I just ran into the same issue :-/